# Apollo Client can't fetch data, because "Failed to parse source map from invariant.ts"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

Apollo Client can't fetch data, because "Failed to parse source map from invariant.ts".[I saw similar problem on forum, but it's outdated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9pMC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be removed by adding `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to your .env file

For more information => https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11752